# How do I refresh a tableview?

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios12

I dare to write here to see if you can help me with a detail that I have when making a query and download an arrangement that can have changes, in short, when making a new record I would like A new query is made to my API to download the new data. I appreciate all comments, thank you very much, greetings to all.

For this I use Model and Protocol.

CitasDetalles.swift

```
import UIKit

class DetallesCitas: NSObject {

var idCitaCliente: String?
var nombreCitaCliente: String?
var idClienteCita: String?
var horarioCita: String?
var fechaCita: String?
var citaStatus: String?
var citaServicio: String?
var citaBarbero: String?

override init(){

}

init(idCitaCliente: String, nombreCitaCliente: String, idClienteCita:String, horarioCita:String, fechaCita: String, citaStatus: String, citaServicio: String, citaBarbero: String) {

    self.idCitaCliente = idCitaCliente
    self.nombreCitaCliente = nombreCitaCliente
    self.idClienteCita = idClienteCita
    self.horarioCita = horarioCita
    self.fechaCita = fechaCita
    self.citaStatus = citaStatus
    self.citaBarbero = citaBarbero

}

override var description: String{

    return "idCitaCliente: \(idCitaCliente), nombreCitaCliente: \(nombreCitaCliente), idClienteCita: \(idClienteCita), horarioCita: \(horarioCita), fechaCita: \(fechaCita), citaStatus: \(citaStatus), citaServicio: \(citaServicio), citaBarbero: \(citaBarbero)"
}
}
```

CitasModelo.swift

```
import UIKit
protocol CitasModeloProtocol: class {

func itemsCitas(lasCitas: NSArray)
}

let idCliente: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: “id”)!

class CitasModelo: NSObject {

weak var elDelegado: CitasModeloProtocol!

let urlPath = "http://sistema.gents.mx/movilBackendGENTS/listaCitasCliente.php?idCliente=\(idCliente)"

func downloadItems(){

    let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
    let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url){
        (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil{

            print("Error al descargas las citas")

        }else{

            print("Datos descargados")

            self.parseJSON(data!)


        }
    }

    task.resume()

}



func parseJSON(_ data:Data){

    var resultFromServer: Any?
    resultFromServer = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

    if let respdict = resultFromServer as? [String : Any] {
        //respone in dictionary format

        var jsonDi = NSDictionary()

        do{

            jsonDi = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

            let parsedJSON = jsonDi
            if parsedJSON["status"] as! String == "401"{

                print(parsedJSON["message"] as! String)

            }

        } catch {


        }



    }

    else if let respArr = resultFromServer as? [Any]{
        //response is array type
            var jsonResult = NSArray()
        do{

            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

        } catch let error as NSError {

            print(error)
        }

        var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
        let detalles = NSMutableArray()
        for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count{

            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary
            let detalle = DetallesCitas()

            let idCitaCliente = jsonElement["id"]
            let nombreCitaCliente = jsonElement["usuarioCita"]
            let idClienteCita = jsonElement["idCliente"]
            let horarioCita = jsonElement["citaHorario"]
            let fechaCita = jsonElement["citaDia"]
            let citaStatus = jsonElement["statusCitas"]
            let citaServicio = jsonElement["citaServicio"]
            let citaBarbero = jsonElement["barberoCita"]

            detalle.idCitaCliente = idCitaCliente as? String
            detalle.nombreCitaCliente = nombreCitaCliente as? String
            detalle.idClienteCita = idClienteCita as? String
            detalle.horarioCita = horarioCita as? String
            detalle.fechaCita = fechaCita as? String
            detalle.citaStatus = citaStatus as? String
            detalle.citaServicio = citaServicio as? String
            detalle.citaBarbero = citaBarbero as? String

            detalles.add(detalle)

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { ()-> Void in

            self.elDelegado.itemsCitas(lasCitas: detalles)
        })

    }

    else if let stringRespt = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8){
        //resp is string
    }


}
}
```

ListaCitasVC.swift

```
import UIKit

class ListaCitasVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CitasModeloProtocol {

var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
var selectCita : DetallesCitas = DetallesCitas()

@IBOutlet weak var citasLista: UITableView!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    citasLista.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.citasLista.delegate = self
    self.citasLista.dataSource = self

    let citasModelo = CitasModelo()
    citasModelo.elDelegado = self
    citasModelo.downloadItems()
    self.citasLista.reloadData()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func itemsCitas(lasCitas: NSArray) {
    feedItems = lasCitas
    self.citasLista.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return feedItems.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "celdaCitas", for: indexPath) as! CitasTVC
    let item: DetallesCitas = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! DetallesCitas

    cell.lblHoraCita!.text = item.horarioCita
    cell.lblFechaCita!.text = item.fechaCita
    cell.lblStatusCitas!.text = item.citaStatus
    cell.lblServicioCita!.text = item.citaServicio
    cell.lblBarbero!.text = item.citaBarbero

    return cell

}

}
```

Comment: Everything seems to be right with the code. In this setup, to reload the data you just need to call `citasModelo.downloadItems()` in the event you want to. What exact error are you facing?

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your response and having read the code. In this app there is a form to create appointments and when the user fills out the form and the information is sent to the server to view that record in the uitableview, when making the whole record and go to the tableview where the registered appointments are stored the tableview does not sample, you would have to uninstall the application and reinstall it so that the application does the whole process of downloading the data from the server, if I close and open the app it does not function to download the data. Thanks greetings.

Comment: The strange part is that, aside the client id, your code don’t store data locally into the app, so when you close and reopen it has nothing saved. Maybe your PHP file is storing cache on the first request and only clean it when called from a reinstalled app. Have you try setting a random token on the url, like: idCliente=xxx&token=63636 ?

Comment: In php you would have to create, say a variable in which you receive data that is randomly generated in swift every time the table is displayed?

Comment: Yeah, just to test if the problem is the PHP file storing cache. If you generate a random token from the app and pass to PHP everytime the table is displayed, the url changes and the cache in the server side should reset

Comment: Great, I will try, excuse my mishandling of English, greetings. Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome. No problems, let us know it this solved the issue.

Comment: 1054/5000
It didn't work, it turns out that my class 'CitasModelo.swift' no longer functions as a download again even though the new token is generated, this token was generated from the view where I have the table like this:
[...]
        token = Int.random (in: 0 .. <10000)

        print ("Token from the list:", token)
        UserDefaults.standard.set (token, forKey: "token")
[...]

Comment: and in my class 'CitasModelo.swift':

[...]
var token: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer (forKey: "token")

class DatingModel: NSObject {


    weak var elDelegado: DatingModelProtocol!


    let urlPath = "http://sistema.gents.mx/movilBackendGENTS/listaCitasCliente.php?idCliente=\(idCliente)&token=\(token)"
[...]

Comment: It is as if it only runs once, download the data, save it and return the data that I already downloaded from the first time even though I am running the table view


I realize why I have that random number printed and it shows me the same time and again, and from where I have the table if it shows that the random numbers are executed

Comment: Can you test the APIs via Postman? If you consult an Id, make a query and then consult the Id again, it works as expected?

Comment: On the server side it works fine, via postman the data in the query changes, on the swift side it executes the query function and saves the result to show that same result that I consulted the first time, in itself it does not function again reload every time I open the tableview

Comment: Ok, can you print the return from the itemCitas(lasCitas: Array) function the second time it is called? Is it exactly the same as the first?

Comment: Sorry about the number of questions, your problem is very strange and I am trying to narrow down the source

Comment: That's right, for example, if I have only one record in the database and I make the query, it returns that same record, if I add more records and return to the tableview without closing the app, the other records I made are not displayed, and Only the result is shown and it is the same as the first query, it is as if it was only executed once since opening the application and saves that same result without executing again.

Comment: I found some things that worth trying.
1) try replacing `Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)` with `Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral)`
2) Add this method before reloading the data:
`URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()`
Let me know if any of those worked

Comment: Sweet! I will post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some ways you can clear the URLSession cache:

1) Replacing `Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)` with `Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral)`

2) Adding this method before reloading the data: `URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()`